# How to do a chi-square test with Yates correction with R

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I did a chi square on R, but my table doesn't show enough people on every cells (< 5), so I need a Yates correction. Anybody know how to do it?
Here's what I got so far:

```
tableau<-table(bdd[,2] , bdd[,4])
tableau
khicarre1<-chisq.test(tableau)
khicarre1
```

I got this message when I launch the test :

> In chisq.test(tableau) : The approximation of Chi-2 is probably incorrect

Comment: the correction is default behaviour...look at `?chisq.test`. Have a look at the text preceding the statistics with example: `chisq.test(matrix(c(1:4), 2))`

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the Yates-correction increases the validity of the chi-squared tests at low N?.

Comment: potentially of interest http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa